NoticationListenerService Pending Intent is not working in Android 14 (targetSdk 34)
I want to open that specific app with a particular screen pending intent, like if I have a WhatsApp notification pending intent, then open the details messages screen of a user who sent that notification on calling.
notification.contentIntent?.send()

it is not working when I set targetSdk=34.
Notification is received from the Notification Listener Service by fetching notifications from other apps. To get notifications from different apps is below:
class NotificationListenService : NotificationListenerService() {
   override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
}
override fun onNotificationRemoved(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
        super.onNotificationRemoved(sbn)
    }

    override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
        super.onNotificationPosted(sbn)
         notification=sbn.notification
    }

}


This question is similar to: How to use NotificationListenerService in Android 14?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
